# Laravel 5.2 [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException] No query results for model [App\Users\BaseUser] in a Queue Job

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-queue

When I pass a User into my queue job (which sends an email to the user) the email sends correctly with the right information however, I get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException]No query results for model [App\Users\BaseUser]
```

BaseUser extends the regular User Model and changes it to use UUID. The user information is there if I var_dump() it in the job handle method. Any idea why this error is being thrown even though all the right information is available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the answer for those who may come upon this question... It was a difference in the front-end. The system I had a question about is an api and I have a staging version and a local dev version, both of which have a demo front-end. The issue came when the demo front-end for the local version sent a user id from staging to local. Be careful not to cross the streams...